# MVC - Binding ICollection property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC and EF DB First. My models are created by EF. In my model i have two ICollection type properties.

My problem is when i post my form, those properties are empty (I'm not sending them to view emty)

My Model:

```
    public partial class Account
    {
        public Account()
        {
            this.Account_Level = new HashSet<Account_Level>();
            this.Account_Team = new HashSet<Account_Team>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Account_Level> Account_Level { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Account_Team> Account_Team { get; set; }
    }
```

Note: My ICollection properties are not present in my view, but i need them back in my controller.

Edit:

I have added below code to my view. In my html, i can see my Icollection values are added as hidden but when i make the post the ICollection properties are still empty. So i am still not getting those values back.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Account_Level.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Account_Level.ElementAt(i).AccountId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Account_Level.ElementAt(i).Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Account_Level.ElementAt(i).LevelId)
}

for (int i = 0; i < Model.Account_Team.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Account_Team.ElementAt(i).AccountId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Account_Team.ElementAt(i).Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Account_Team.ElementAt(i).TeamId)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain if you dont need it in your view than why do you need them to have a round trip and again available after post or why they need to be part of the view model

Comment: Make the collections `IList` and use indexing `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Account_Level[i].AccountId)` But it seems pointless - far better to get the collections in the server on post back rather that doing this

Comment: @StephenMuecke Will do that, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that the `DefaultModelBinder` is not able to bind your hidden fields to your model, because **your hidden fields are not following the correct naming convention**.

The HiddenFor method in your Razor view generates something like:

```
<input id="AccountId" type="hidden" value="1" name="AccountId" data-val-required="The AccountId field is required." data-val-number="The field AccountId must be a number." data-val="true">
```

As you see the generated name is `AccountId` which is not correct if you want to make it bindable.

The correct name must be something like `Account_Level[0].AccountId`.

Here is a full example of the correct naming for your hidden fields:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Account_Level.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Account_Level.ElementAt(i).AccountId, new { @Name = string.Format("Account_Level[{0}].AccountId", i) })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Account_Level.ElementAt(i).Id, new { @Name = string.Format("Account_Level[{0}].Id", i) })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Account_Level.ElementAt(i).LevelId, new { @Name = string.Format("Account_Level[{0}].LevelId", i) })
}
```

This will make sure your hidden fields names are recognized by the default model binder.

Here you can find more information about the ASP.NET MVC naming conventions:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/